# AFNetworking 2 POST with Authentication challenge

Tags: afnetworking

Im using AFNetworking 2, with AFHTTPRequestOperation I can use for my Get

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
    [operation setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:
     ^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
    //the certificate
    }
 [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        DLog(@"operation :: %@", responseObject);
        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        DLog(@"operation :: %@", result);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        DLog(@"operation error :: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
```

But now i need to use POST, with parameters,

I have problems finding how to set parameters on

> AFHTTPRequestOperation

or  finding how to set challenge block for

> AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

how to have  a POST with parameters and challenge block?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working now on the POST request. So far I've came up with the following code while trying to send an NSDictionary with POST method:

```
    NSDictionary*packet = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: ......

    [manager POST:path
       parameters:packet
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
                 if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                     [self parseReceivedDataPacket:responseObject];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

Actually it works for me, apart from getting an "unacceptable content-type: text/html" when sending this data. But it gets received.

Hope this was useful.